# Airflow worker trying to connect to redis despite rabbitmq configuration

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, rhel7, airflow

I installed and set up Airflow 2.0.1 with Celery, Rabbitmq and Postgresql9.6 on RHEL7, using the constraints https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.0.1/constraints-3.7.txt.
So I am not using Docker container, and in fact am building a cluster with 3 nodes.

I created DB and username for PSQL, and created user and set permission for Rabbitmq and am able to access its WebUI in 15672 port.
I am able to run airflow webserver and scheduler and access airflow WebUI with no problem.

The issue arises when I try to start airflow worker (whether from master node or worker nodes). Even though airflow.cfg is set to point out to rabbitmq, I get the error that says:

```
ImportError: Missing redis library (pip install redis)
```

Because it is trying to access redis instead of rabbitmq, but I have no idea why.

I checked airflow.cfg line by line and there is not a single line with redis, so am I missing a configuration or what?

My airflow.cfg configuration:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:airflow_pw@10.200.159.59:5432/airflow
broker_url= amqp://rabbitmq_user:rabbitmq_pw@10.200.159.59:5672/airflow_virtual_host
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://airflow_user:airflow_pw@10.200.159.59:5432/airflow

dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
load_examples = False
```

Why does my airflow worker try to reach redis when it is configured for rabbitmq?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem after spending many hours on such a simple, silly issue.

Airflow still tried to connect to redis, which isthe default Airflow config despite my rabbitmq configuration in airflow.cfg because I had written all of the configs under [core] section, wheras lines must be written to related parts in airflow.cfg.

I moved broker_url and result_backend to under [celery] and issue was resolved.